# Gradle version used by Codename One sources for Android

Tags: codenameone

What is the current Gradle version used by Codename One sources for Android? I'm trying to open a Codename One project with the current version of Android Studio without success, as you can see by the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently use Gradle 4.6 for builds, setting it in the external gradle option should help.